# Blender 2.8 fbx import/export not available in final version

Tags: export, import

Even in final 2.8 version of blender, still I don't have access to fbx import/export options. The only import/export options are ambelic and collada. how can I fix it ?

Comment: Have you enabled the add-ons in Edit > Preferences > Add-ons?

Comment: Yes. and some add-ons like Blender Kit and Hard ops work, but fbx import/export addon or unreal import export (that works with fbx) do not appear on tabs. First, I assumed because blender was under development some add-ons were disabled but now that final release is available, still have that issue, which practically made 2.8 unusable for me

Comment: as I said only ambelic and collada import/export are available to me (2.8 stable release version)

Comment: I'd recommend to factory reset (backup your keymap and other changes first if you want to restore them later one) File > Default > Load Factory Setting.

Comment: Huh. It worked. Thank you very much

Comment: I found what causes that. When I create a new file going with File->New->General, that's when layout changes (all workspace tabs disappear) and import/export options set limited to alembic and collada.

Comment: To fix that, we have to save the start up file. Then New->General works properly